# How to stop CKEditor replacing empty tags with <br>

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

is there a way to prevent CKEditor inserting br in empty tags and stop removing the wrapper element.

For example:

When i add something into the editor , by default a pair of 'p' appears.

```
<div>
   <p>content</p>
</div>
```

but when i delete the 'content' it is replaced and the dom looks something like this:

```
<p>
  br 
  ""
</p>
```

How to disable this default behaviour? In my case i want to have:

```
<div>
  <p>
   <br>
  <p/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backspace/delete (and many other behaviours) are implemented by the browser and may work differently depending on the engine. CKEditor overrides some of them (usually, the most broken), but I don't think it handles this case.

Anyway, the solution is to handle backspace in a custom way, but the most straightforward way, which is reimplementing backspace behaviour, will not be easy due to number of cases. Therefore, I would try some workaround - e.g. fixing the DOM after backspace. It would be something like:

1. Listen to [`editor#key`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-key) event and check position of the selection and the DOM. Remember whether it matches the situation which you want to fix.
2. Wait few ms, or until `#keyup` event and fix the DOM and selection as you would like them to be.

Also, read [Listening to DOM events in CKEditor](https://gist.github.com/Reinmar/9665f1630cd6287b4c2b) in case of any problems with listeners that are not executed.